# PHP object return false if no properties

Tags: php, class, object, properties, logic

I am trying to make a class what will contain a set of properties. it will be used like so:

```
$class = new test_class();

$class->property;
$class->second_property;
```

Basically, if the properties exist, then they are true, if the properties do not exist, they are false. The properties have no value, only existence.

Now, I want to do something like this:

```
$class = new test_class();

var_dump($class->property); // false - property does not exist
var_dump($class->second_property); // true - second_property exists

var_dump( (bool) $class); // true
```

So if even one property of the test class exists, var dumping the `$class` will show true because it is an object.

However, in the situation where the class has no properties, I want this to happen:

```
$class = new test_class();

var_dump($class->property); // false - property does not exist
var_dump($class->second_property); // false - second_property does not exist

var_dump( (bool) $class); // false
```

But, I still want `$class` to be `instanceof` the `test_class` but return false in a logic test.

Is this at all possible? If so, how would I do it?

Thanks, Ozzy

**edit:**

To clarify, I am already using the __get() magic function. What I want to happen is if the `test_class` has no properties, then when a `var_dump` is performed on it, it returns false but an `instanceof` will return `test_class`.

**elaborating...**

I am creating a complex permissions system. 
A user gets assigned sections and each section has a set of permissions.

It will work like this:

```
$user = permissions::get_user(USER_ID_HERE);
// Every property of the $user is a section

var_dump($user->this_section_exists); // true - returns an object
var_dump($user->this_section_doesnt); // false - returns a boolean
```

If a section exists, then it returns an object of the sections permissions.

```
var_dump($user->this_section_exists); // true
var_dump($user->this_section_exists->this_permission_exists); // true

var_dump($user->this_section_exists->this_permission_doesnt); // false
```

Heres the edge case:

```
var_dump($user->this_section_doesnt); // false

var_dump($user->this_section_doesnt->some_permission);
// This should also return false, which it does,
// But it throws a notice: "Trying to get property of non-object"
```

I want to be able to either suppress that notice without any modifications to the code which calls the class, ie, no @ to suppress.. or be able to return an object with no properties which evaluates to false on a logic test.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `class a { public function is_valid() { return $this->a && $this->b } }` ?

Comment: Can you elaborate why you want to have this functionality? It looks like the concept itself is flawed, so maybe there is a better alternative.

Comment: Without a proper background this question is bogus, please elaborate why you need this behaviour.

Comment: added the background to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to happen is if the test_class has no properties, then when a var_dump is performed on it, it returns false but an instanceof will return test_class.

That is not possible, `var_dump` will always show you the correct type, that's what it was made for.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it exactly as you wrote it. But you can emulate something similar:

```
class A {

    public function __toString() { // this is what you want, but it only works when you use your object as a string, not as a bool.
        if (count(get_class_vars(__CLASS__))) { // so if the class has at least 1 attribute, it will return 1.
            return '1';
        } else {
            return '0';
        }
    }
}

$a = new A;
var_dump((bool)(string)$a); // false
```

If I add a propery in A class it will return true. You can also use it without `(bool)`.

```
if ((string)$a) {
    echo 'I am not empty';
} else {
    echo 'I am an empty object';
}
```

If you don't want to use `(string)`, you have one option left, to create a method that contains the code from `__toString()` and call it instead of casting.

References:

- [__toString()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring)
- [get_class_vars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php)
- [`__CLASS__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

PS: About what you said - doing a `var_dump()` on the object to return false. No, that is not possible.

Answer (score -1):

You can try [PHP magic function](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)

```
<?php

class Test {

    private $name = 'name';

    public $age = 20;

    public function __get($name) {
        return isset($this->$name) ? true : false;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return true;
    }

}

$object = new Test();

var_dump($object->name); // output `true`
var_dump($object->age); // output `20`
var_dump($object->notfound); // output `false`
var_dump((bool)$object); // output `true`
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do some wrapping with [__get()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) to manipulate the answer.

Say something like

```
class test_class {

  private $_validProperties;
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->validProperties = array('foo', 'bar', 'widget');
  }

  public function __get($prop)
  {
    if (isset($this->_validProperties[$prop])
    {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}

$a = new test_class();
var_dump($a->foo); //true
var_dump($a->tree); //false
```

Comment: Ok, thats great until we get to my final part of the question, if `$this->validProperties` has no property, then a `var_dump` of any property will be false. In this scenario, I also want `var_dump($a)` to be false but not to throw a notice "Trying to get property of non-object"  when you try to access a property of `$a` like `$a->property`.

Comment: You're kind of stuck as far as I know. You could start off with `$a` being false, and not instantiate it until you assign the first property. If you're willing to cast it to a string you could do something like `public function __toString() { if (count($this->_validProperties) == 0) { return 'false'; } return 'true'}

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, I can only do so.

Hope it can help you

```
<?php
class Permissions {
    private $userPermissions = array(
        1 => array(
            'Blog' => array('Post'),
        ),
    );

    private $permission;

    public function __construct($id) {
        $this->permission = $this->userPermissions[$id];
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        if(isset($this->permission[$name])) {
            return new $name($this->permission[$name]);
        }
        return new Notfound();
    }

}

class Blog {
    private $permission;

    public function __construct($permission) {
        $this->permission = $permission;
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        if(($key = array_search($name, $this->permission)) !== false) {
            return new $name();
        }
        return new Notfound();
    }

    public function __tostring() {
        return true;
    }
}

class Post {
    public function __get($name) {
        return isset($this->$name) ? true : new Notfound();
    }
    public function __tostring() {
        return true;
    }
}

class Notfound {
    public function __get($name) {
        return false;
    }
    public function __tostring() {
        return false;
    }
}

$user = new Permissions(1);
var_dump('Blog ', $user->Blog); // return Blog
var_dump('Blog:Post', $user->Blog->Post); // return Post
var_dump('News', $user->News); // return Notfound
var_dump('News:Post', $user->News->Post); // return false
```